# How to bind a std::map to Lua with LuaBind

Tags: c++, stl, lua, luabind

I'm trying to expose my `std::map<std::string, std::string>` as a class property to Lua. I've set this method for my getter and setter:

```
luabind::object FakeScript::GetSetProperties()
{
    luabind::object table = luabind::newtable(L);
    luabind::object metatable = luabind::newtable(L);

    metatable["__index"] = &this->GetMeta;
    metatable["__newindex"] = &this->SetMeta;

    luabind::setmetatable<luabind::object, luabind::object>(table, metatable);

    return table;
}
```

This way it makes me able to do something like this in Lua:

```
player.scripts["movement"].properties["stat"] = "idle"
print(player.scripts["movement"].properties["stat"])
```

However, the code I've provided in C++ doesn't getting compiled. It tells me there is an ambiguous call to overloaded function at this line `metatable["__index"] = &this->GetMeta;` and the line after it. I'm not sure that I'm doing this correctly.

Error message:

```
error C2668: 'luabind::detail::check_const_pointer' : 
ambiguous call to overloaded function
c:\libraries\luabind-0.9.1\references\luabind\include\luabind\detail\instance_holder.hpp    75
```

These are `SetMeta` and `GetMeta` in `FakeScript`:

```
static void GetMeta();
static void SetMeta();
```

Previously I was doing this for getter method:

```
luabind::object FakeScript::getProp()
{
    luabind::object obj = luabind::newtable(L);

    for(auto i = this->properties.begin(); i != this->properties.end(); i++)
    {
        obj[i->first] = i->second;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

This works fine, but it's not letting me to use setter method. For example:

```
player.scripts["movement"].properties["stat"] = "idle"
print(player.scripts["movement"].properties["stat"])
```

In this code it just going to trigger getter method in both lines. Although if it was letting me to use setter, I wouldn't be able to get key from properties which it is `["stat"]` right here.

Is there any expert on LuaBind here? I've seen most of people say they've never worked with it before.

Comment: Put the full error message as you see it, in your question please.

Comment: @greatwolf I've put it.

Comment: The error should show what the candidate functions are.

Comment: Well this is all I get. Actually I need someone to tell me how to assign functions for metatable fields in LuaBind way. See, I can change this to use a function to access my map instead of a property, but I'm concerned about user's programming style.

Comment: What does `FakeScript::GetMeta` and `FakeScript::SetMeta` look like? Those aren't functions you're trying to bind, they're class methods.

Comment: They're static class methods. There is no difference If I place functions instead of them. I've put their definitions.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the (undocumented) `make_function()` to make objects from functions.

```
metatable["__index"] = luabind::make_function(L, &this->GetMeta);
metatable["__newindex"] = luabind::make_function(L, &this->GetMeta);
```

Unfortunately, this (the simplest) overload of `make_function` is broken, but you just need to [insert  `f`](https://github.com/Oberon00/luabind/commit/2bae0ab83ca69f36347e8efe09d6cc5fb3517d84) as the second parameter in `make_function.hpp`.

Comment: Actually I tried that before I come here. I couldn't get it to work because of overload's corruption so I dumped it away. Now you helped me all the way! I'm going to try that, but I came up with another approach to use function overloads to achieve my need.